# Отображение блоков в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть 6 картинки которые стоят в столбик, мне нужно чтобы в мобильной версии они располагались по 2 в каждом ряду.

Но почему-то не работает. Подскажите в чем проблема? как расположить их по 2 в каждом ряду?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.picture-box {
  width: 70%; /* limit screen width - max width could have been used aswell */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ring {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center; /* Center ring div */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   .ring {
      width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .ring {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .ring {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .picture-box {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А что вы делаете, что бы было по 2 картинки в строке? Я не вижу таких свойств.

Comment: @E_K padding дал. можете пояснить?

Answer (score 1):

Добавь `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {.picture-box { flex-direction:column; }}`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.picture-box {
  width: 70%; /* limit screen width - max width could have been used aswell */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ring {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center; /* Center ring div */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   .ring {
      width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .ring {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .ring {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .picture-box {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .picture-box {
    flex-direction:column;
    }
}

.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали размеры блока с картинками, поэтому `flex` контейнер вмещает в одну строку столько картинок, сколько позволит размер. Из за свойства `flex-wrap: wrap` остальное переносится на следующую строку.

Вам нужно указать размер блока `.ring` для нужных размеров экрана, что бы для мобильных получить 2 блока в ряд нужна ширина `50%` (это без учета `margin`). Стоит учитывать размеры изображения, если они будут фиксированые блоки всеравно будут смещаться, так как не подходят по размеру. Для этого можно сделать `responsive` изображения или использовать `overflow: hidden`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.picture-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
}

.ring {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}


.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .ring {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - (40px / 3))
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1240px) {
  .ring {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 6) - (100px / 6))
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: дело в том, что мне нужно чтобы у них `flex-direction` был не `row` а `column`, я исправил, но теперь они не по 2 штуки в ряд а друг под другом. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вопрос нужно задавать корректно изначально. Что бы изменить нужно заменить свойство `flex` на `width` с тем же значением ширины и ограничить высоту `flex` контейнера.

Comment: я сделал так как вы сказали, но не получилось. Я добавил обновленный код в вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.